# Error when trying to pip install Sphinx

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-sphinx, windows-7-x64, maya

I am trying to install Sphinx with pip on the command prompt. I've installed many other plugins such as virtualenv, setup tools, nose2. However when i tried installing Sphinx, it gave the following error:

```
pip install Sphinx

>>> (...long install text....)

Command ""c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\mayapy.exe" -u -c "import setup
tools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\gregory\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-6l
83ci\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" ins
tall --record c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-juw8vj-record\install-reco
rd.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 i
n c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6l83ci\MarkupSafe\
```

I am using the mayapy.exe python interpreter for Maya 2015 (python 2.7.3), not the standard python interpreter, but I havent had any trouble thusfar with it. It shows all the install text, but at the end the error above is in red and Sphinx is not installed.

Is there anything i'm missing or doing wrong here?

--- Edit ---

This is what I got from the stack trace, it says that upgrading the python version can prevent what is happening but the python version is locked to the application. Not sure what to do.

```
Command ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\bin\mayapy.exe" -u -c "
import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\gregory\\appdata\\local
\\temp\\pip-build-scwdtn\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
 install --record c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-uel6g6-record\install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\gregory\
appdata\local\temp\pip-build-scwdtn\MarkupSafe\C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\Python\lib\
site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: 
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately 
and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve 
this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

-- Edit --

I'm getting this now, with the ssl error no longer showing.

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\Python\Scripts>pip install -U Sphinx
Collecting Sphinx
  Using cached Sphinx-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils>=0.11 in c:\program files\autodesk\maya
2015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 in c:\program files\autodesk
\maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: snowballstemmer>=1.1 in c:\program files\autodes
k\maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: Pygments>=2.0 in c:\program files\autodesk\maya2
015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: sphinxcontrib-websupport in c:\program files\aut
odesk\maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\p
ython\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: imagesize in c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\
python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.3 (from Sphinx)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama>=0.3.5; sys_platform == "win32" (from Sphinx)
  Using cached colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing; python_version < "3.5" (from Sphinx)
  Using cached typing-3.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting babel!=2.0,>=1.3 (from Sphinx)
  Using cached Babel-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015
\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\autodesk\may
a2015\python\lib\site-packages (from Sphinx)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.3->Sphinx)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting pytz>=0a (from babel!=2.0,>=1.3->Sphinx)
  Using cached pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in c:\program files\autode
sk\maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in c:\program files\autodesk\maya
2015\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\program files\autodesk\
maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx)
Requirement already up-to-date: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\program files\autode
sk\maya2015\python\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->Sphinx)
Building wheels for collected packages: typing, MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for typing ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Gregory\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\b3\54\d1\
d7ad0895b6f57c608afdf3ec5d2339c5d18ffcf2c2e0e0d9aa
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... error
  Complete output from command "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\mayapy.ex
e" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\gregory\\appdata\\loc
al\\temp\\pip-build-jwlwl9\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', op
en)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, _
_file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\tmpenjqanp
ip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  running egg_info
  writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
  running build_ext
  building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setup.
py", line 132, in <module>
      try_building_extension()
    File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setup.
py", line 111, in try_building_extension
      run_setup(True)
    File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setup.
py", line 105, in run_setup
      features=features,
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\core.py"
, line 152, in setup
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.py"
, line 953, in run_commands
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.py"
, line 972, in run_command
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdis
t_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\cmd.py",
 line 326, in run_command
      continue
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.py"
, line 972, in run_command
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\command\
build.py", line 127, in run
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\cmd.py",
 line 326, in run_command
      continue
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.py"
, line 972, in run_command
    File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setup.
py", line 52, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\command\
build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\command\
build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setup.
py", line 58, in build_extension
      build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\command\
build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9com
piler.py", line 473, in compile
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9com
piler.py", line 383, in initialize
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools
\msvc.py", line 128, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
      return orig(ver, arch, *args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9com
piler.py", line 266, in query_vcvarsall
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools
\msvc.py", line 94, in msvc9_find_vcvarsall
      return get_unpatched(msvc9_find_vcvarsall)(version)
    File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9com
piler.py", line 243, in find_vcvarsall
  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py clean for MarkupSafe
Successfully built typing
Failed to build MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, colorama, typing, pytz, babel
, Sphinx
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\mayapy.
exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\gregory\\appdata\\l
ocal\\temp\\pip-build-jwlwl9\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open',
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-ch
rjra-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    copying markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    running egg_info
    writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\markupsafe
    running build_ext
    building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setu
p.py", line 132, in <module>
        try_building_extension()
      File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setu
p.py", line 111, in try_building_extension
        run_setup(True)
      File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setu
p.py", line 105, in run_setup
        features=features,
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\core.p
y", line 152, in setup
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.p
y", line 953, in run_commands
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.p
y", line 972, in run_command
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptoo
ls\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\comman
d\install.py", line 563, in run
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\cmd.py
", line 326, in run_command
        continue
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.p
y", line 972, in run_command
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\comman
d\build.py", line 127, in run
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\cmd.py
", line 326, in run_command
        continue
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\dist.p
y", line 972, in run_command
      File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setu
p.py", line 52, in run
        build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\comman
d\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\comman
d\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      File "c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\setu
p.py", line 58, in build_extension
        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\comman
d\build_ext.py", line 498, in build_extension
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9c
ompiler.py", line 473, in compile
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9c
ompiler.py", line 383, in initialize
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptoo
ls\msvc.py", line 128, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
        return orig(ver, arch, *args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9c
ompiler.py", line 266, in query_vcvarsall
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptoo
ls\msvc.py", line 94, in msvc9_find_vcvarsall
        return get_unpatched(msvc9_find_vcvarsall)(version)
      File "c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\python27.zip\distutils\msvc9c
ompiler.py", line 243, in find_vcvarsall
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\autodesk\maya2015\bin\mayapy.exe" -u -c "import setup
tools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\gregory\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-jw
lwl9\\MarkupSafe\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" ins
tall --record c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-chrjra-record\install-reco
rd.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 i
n c:\users\gregory\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jwlwl9\MarkupSafe\

C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\Python\Scripts>
```

Comment: do you want to install packages for Maya 2015 ?

Comment: Yes, i'm installing packages for maya 2015, not the standard python library. When i use pip install I set my current directory in the command prompt to the Autodesk > Maya2015 > Python > Scripts Folder (where everything else is installed). My IDE is also set to use the maya python interpreter as well.

Comment: try installing markupsafe maybe you get a proper stack trace

Comment: I got a more detailed stack trace, not sure how to resolve this. I posted an edit above.

Comment: you have missing ssl deps (try installing a python and copy the pyd files from the root and the Lib folder (do not overwrite files)

Comment: The only pyd files i found were in the DLL folder, and the only one that was in python 2.7.3. that wasnt in the maya python was _msi.pyd, but I still get the same error. The root Python27 folder didnt have any, and the lib folder only has .py files and folders with .py files. I tried just copying all the files and folders over and it still didnt do anything

Comment: Check the dll folder as well you may copy folders from Lib

Comment: I took all the extra folders from my python 2.7.3, and put the extras in the maya python (not overwriting anything). I also installed requests[security] and directly installing pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 as per suggestion from other places. I've also reset my computer, tried from command line, from within script, running multiple times. Nothing seems to work, yet I can pip install other things, just not Sphinx. Since my python version is locked to 2.7.3 I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: try to upgrade pip: `pip install pip setuptools wheel -U`

Comment: Yeah, now it just says failed building wheel for markupsafe. and i dont believe markup safe is installed, because it just gives me an error trying to install it, but setuptools, pip, and wheel are all up to date

Comment: "building wheel for markupsafe" (try to download the wheel and install it)

Comment: worst case install visual studio 2015